# Dividing one column by another based on values on other columns and getting the sum

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In the following image, what I'm trying to do is to find a formula that will divide values on column C by values on column L, ONLY IF:

- Value on column D = "L", and
- Value on column J = "Right", and
- Value on column K = "C", and
- Value on column L <> 0 (isn't empty)

And then return the sum of those divisions.

So, for example, in this image, it would first:
- Divide C7 by L7, then
- Divide C12 by L12, then
- Divide C15 by L15, and finally
- Return the sum of the results of those divisions.

I have made multiple attempts with arrayformulas and sum(if) conjugates, to no sucess.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Test sheet]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it, then you need this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D7; "L"; 
             J7; "Right"; 
             K7; "C"; 
             L7; "<>"); C7/L7; ; )
```

and then drag it down where it's needed...